# How do I serially declare structs without making them arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, struct

I'm currently having a bit of trouble with arrays of structs (specifically, my array is so big that it takes up seven megabytes of memory), and I'm beginning to question whether I really need to declare all the structs at one time and hog the memory like that, rather than increment it proportionally as new structs are needed (the program reads stuff from a file, and I store the data from the file in the structs; but the number of things it needs to read from the file is unpredictable). What alternative can I use so that the program can refer to individual, unique structs, but doesn't need the exact number of structs in advance?

Comment: Dynamic allocation with `malloc` and `realloc`? (Don't forget `free`, then.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Linked lists?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) Or any other more advanced data structures, depending on your purpose, but in any case some reading seems to be in order :) Or if you're doing C++, just use std::list.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways come up to my mind:

- a reallocable array (which could be of structs or pointer to structs), you would need functions to check if you are going outside bounds and realloc the whole array in case (with `realloc`)
- a linked list of structs, grows automatically when needed, insertion and deletion are constant but you won't have fast random access indexing of the elements

for the linked list solution you would just need another struct

```
struct node
{
  struct node *prev; // if you want it double linked
  struct node *next;
  struct data data;
};
```

Which one to choose mainly depends on the frequency with which new items must be added to the data structure, if it is done in batch then reallocing would be quite efficient, otherwise you'll do many reallocs (you can always use an approach similar to the one used for hashmaps and increment it always by a big amount, eg by doubling the capacity). If you need fast random access forget about linked lists.

Comment: Okay, this is great! I'll probably use this. But what's fast "random" access?

Comment: random access is when you need to access elements at specified indices instead that accessing them sequentially (eg. in a loop). If you need to access elements data[4], data[11] and so on many times then linked lists are not the solution for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `union` instead of a `strust`; it is much more memory efficient and does not hog memory like a `struct` does.

Comment: -1: A `struct` holds a number of sub-elements (in the order specified, perhaps with some padding between them). A `union` holds just _one_ of a set of sub-elements (and you must remember which one you last stored). In general they are _not_ interchangeable.